# std::unique not working as expected with struct

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm currently working on a 2D game where the level is defined by edges:

```
struct Edge
{
    vec2int start;
    vec2int end;
}
```

The struct `vec2int` is a vector with x, y coordinates and has all needed operators (in this particular case `operator==`) overloaded.
Because of a data structure that stores the edges inside of a grid, there can be duplicate edges in different cells inside the grid. When combining them back into a single `std::vector<Edge>` I tried to get rid of them like this:

```
auto it = std::unique(
    edges.begin(),
    edges.end(),
    [&](const Edge& e1, const Edge& e2)
    {
        return e1.start == e2.start && e1.end == e2.end;
    });

edges.resize(std::distance(edges.begin(), it));
```

For whatever reason this deletes only a few (or none) of the duplicate edges. I have no idea why. Is there something I am missing about `std::unique`?

The code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct v2d_generic
{
    T x = 0;
    T y = 0;
    
    bool operator==(const v2d_generic& rhs) const
    {
        return (this->x == rhs.x && this->y == rhs.y);
    }
    bool operator!=(const v2d_generic& rhs) const
    {
        return (this->x != rhs.x || this->y != rhs.y);
    }
};

typedef v2d_generic<int> vec2i;

struct Edge
{
    vec2i start;
    vec2i end;
};


int main(void)
{
    std::vector<Edge> edges;

    edges.push_back(Edge{vec2i{1, 1}, vec2i{1, 1}});
    edges.push_back(Edge{vec2i{1, 1}, vec2i{1, 2}});
    edges.push_back(Edge{vec2i{1, 1}, vec2i{1, 1}});
    edges.push_back(Edge{vec2i{1, 1}, vec2i{1, 2}});

    std::cout << edges.size() << std::endl;

    auto it = std::unique(
        edges.begin(),
        edges.end(),
        [&](const Edge& e1, const Edge& e2)
        {
            return e1.start == e2.start && e1.end == e2.end;
        });

    edges.resize(std::distance(edges.begin(), it));

    std::cout << edges.size() << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs 4 both times.

Comment: Assuming `vec2f` has `float` members you are running into the classic problem of floating point inaccuracies (which is why comparing `float`s for equality basically doesn't work)

Comment: Small optimization: Instead of `edges.resize(std::distance(edges.begin(), it));`, you can do `edges.erase(it, edges.end())`.

Comment: @UnholySheep even though thats the case there are only ints stored in vec2f. Even changing to a version where I account for the inaccuracies, nothing changes. I changed it to vec2int cause its less confusing. Thank you!

Comment: @0x5453 I saw both ways on the internet. Is working with erase faster?

Comment: can you show your [example] and input, expected output, and actual output please? I can't compile this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::unique` removes *consecutive* equivalent elements. In your example, you do not have consecutive equal elements, so it should not remove anything.

If you do not care about the order of the elements in your range, you can sort it before calling `std::unique`.